# Unexpected type conversion when using C-style variadics to pass doubles

Tags: c++, class, templates, variadic-functions, ellipsis

I tried a variable Args. The Matrix class works with int but when i use double i got wrong values with 23 when i dont convert it. I read that other types are automaticly converted

- float arguments are converted to double as in floating-point promotion
- bool, char, short, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in integer promotion" i don't get it why i get wrong values.

```cpp
#include "matrix.h"
//#include "coordinate_sys.h"

int main(){

//Coordinate_3d<double>Coordinate_3(1,2,3);
//Coordinate_3.print_console();

Matrix<double>sick_matrix(2,2,4,20.5,(double)23,23,0);
sick_matrix.print_console();

while(1){}

return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

template<typename T>
class Matrix{
private:
    T * arr_ptr;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
    
public:
    Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols, unsigned int args_ctr,...): rows(rows),cols(cols){
        //react to false input
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if(cols * rows < args_ctr){ //to many args
            std::cout << "Matrix initilization with to many arguments" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        arr_ptr = new T[rows*cols];
        va_list args;
        unsigned int fill_var = 0;
        va_start(args,args_ctr);

        while (fill_var < args_ctr)
        {
            arr_ptr[fill_var] = va_arg(args,T);
            fill_var++;
        }
        
        va_end(args);   
    }

    void print_console(){for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++){std::cout << arr_ptr[i] << std::endl;}}

};

#endif
```

Im going to do this with variable Template arguments but why is that error in the conversion?

Comment: Pop quiz: what is the type of `23` and `0`? The shown code will expect them to be `double`s, of course. Are they?

Comment: And this is exactly why C-style variadic parameters should be avoided in C++. You lose all type safety with them. Use C++-style variadic templates instead, or in this case `std::initializer_list` would suffice, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that C-style variadic arguments give you absolutely no type safety.
`(double)23,23,0` passes a `double` and two `int`s, and you expect three `double`s in the constructor.

You should generally stay away from C-style variadics in C++.

#### Solution A - `std::initializer_list`

```cpp
Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols, std::initializer_list<T> args)
  : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
    // args.size() can be used to obtain the number of arguments
}
```

#### Solution B - statically sized matrix

In almost all cases, you know the size of a matrix at compile time anyway. A lot of issues becomes trivial to solve if you turn the rows and columns into  non-type template parameters:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Columns = Rows>
class Matrix {
  private:
    // ...
  public:
    T data[Rows * Columns];
};
```

You don't even need a constructor anymore, and could write:

```cpp
using Mat3f = Matrix<float, 3>; // convenience alias

Mat3f mat{/* ... */}; // aggregate initialization, no constructor needed
```

If you insisted on having a constructor, it could be a constructor taking just one parameter of type `std::initializer_list<T>`, and you could still use the syntax `Mat3f{...}`.